# VBA to look up non 0 values in cell range and return multiple row and column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I am an absolute beginner with VBA and looking for some help!

I have identical tables on multiple tabs which hold labour activity data,

I need a VBA to look for all non 0 values in the range and bring back values from the rows and columns that those values are found (namely headers).

Shift 1 data on 1st sheet:

[image]

Shift 2 Data on 2nd sheet:

[image]

Required Result on 3rd sheet:
[image]

Alternatively, I could live with it working for one sheet, and then attempt a VBA to consolidate, but ideally it would do the consolidation as well.

Managed to combine various solutions from Google but that was painfully slow and my knowledge is really minimal, can make it work with index/match/indirect but the formula really cloggs up my spreadsheet

I'm using 365

Thanks in advance

Edit** Tables Added

Shift 1
01/01/2023

```
        1   2   3   1   2   3   <<Role
```

Factory Area    Reporting Category  Labour Type John    Jack    Joe Jane    Mary    Sue <<< Name
Area 1  Category 1  Type 1  12                      <<<Hours
Area 1  Category 2  Type 2      12              10
Area 1  Category 3  Type 1          6   8
Area 1  Category 4  Type 1          6
Area 2  Category 5  Type 1                  12
Area 2  Category 6  Type 2
Area 2  Category 7  Type 1              4       2
Area 2  Category 8  Type 2

Shift 2
02/01/2023

```
        1   2   3   1   2   3   <<Role
```

Factory Area    Reporting Category  Labour Type Dale    Damien  Dave    Claire  Cara    Charlotte   <<< Name
Area 1  Category 1  Type 1                      12  <<<Hours
Area 1  Category 2  Type 2  12          2   12
Area 1  Category 3  Type 1
Area 1  Category 4  Type 1      12
Area 2  Category 5  Type 1          12
Area 2  Category 6  Type 2
Area 2  Category 7  Type 1              10
Area 2  Category 8  Type 2

```
Comments        abc     def     ghi
```

Shift   Date    Area    Reporting Category  Labour Type Name    Role    Hours   Comments
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 1  Category 1  Type 1  John    1   12
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 1  Category 2  Type 2  Jack    2   12
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 1  Category 2  Type 2  Sue 3   10
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 1  Category 3  Type 1  Joe     3   6
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 1  Category 3  Type 1  Jane    1   8
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 1  Category 4  Type 1  Joe     3   6
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 2  Category 5  Type 1  Mary    2   12
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 2  Category 7  Type 1  Jane    1   4
Shift 1 01/01/2023  Area 2  Category 7  Type 1  Sue 3   2
Shift 2 02/01/2023  Area 1  Category 1  Type 1  Charlotte   3   12
Shift 2 02/01/2023  Area 1  Category 2  Type 2  Dale    1   12  abc
Shift 2 02/01/2023  Area 1  Category 2  Type 2  Claire  1   2
Shift 2 02/01/2023  Area 1  Category 2  Type 2  Cara    2   12  ghi
Shift 2 02/01/2023  Area 1  Category 4  Type 1  Damien  2   12
Shift 2 02/01/2023  Area 2  Category 5  Type 1  Dave    3   12  def
Shift 2 02/01/2023  Area 2  Category 7  Type 1  Claire  1   10

Comment: Your links don't work for me (and even if they did Image sites are blocked at work). Why not put the data into a table into your question.
As to a solution, I would use Power Query for this sort of work

Comment: Ive tried  to add text file data but it hasnt worked, i think ill look for a forum where i can add excel files

Comment: Here: https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/ you can simply format your excel table to markdown and then copy/paste in your post

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data shown is representative of the actual layout of your worksheets, something like this should work for you:

```
Sub CreateLabourSummary()
    
    'Declare workbook and worksheet objects
    Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet: Set wsSummary = wb.Worksheets("Summary")    'Set this to the actual name of the worksheet that will contain the summary table
    
    'Prepare results array
    Dim aResults() As Variant:  ReDim aResults(1 To 1000, 1 To 9)   'Increase max rows of results array if necessary
    Dim iResultRow As Long
    
    'Prepare loop variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim aComments() As Variant
    Dim sShift As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim iDataRow As Long, iDataCol As Long
    
    'Loop through each worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        'Exclude sheets that don't contain the data that needs to be summarized
        '  Skip the summary sheet
        '  Skip any sheets that don't adhere to the labour activity data format
        If ws.Name <> wsSummary.Name Then
            If IsDate(ws.Range("A2").Value) And ws.Range("A5").Value = "Factory Area" Then
                sShift = ws.Range("A1").Value
                dtDate = ws.Range("A2").Value
                aData = ws.Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Value
                aComments = ws.Range("A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, UBound(aData, 2)).Value
                For iDataRow = 3 To UBound(aData, 1)    'Start at 3 to skip the header rows
                    For iDataCol = 4 To UBound(aData, 2)    'Start at 4 to check for values > 0
                        If aData(iDataRow, iDataCol) > 0 Then
                            iResultRow = iResultRow + 1
                            aResults(iResultRow, 1) = sShift                    'Shift
                            aResults(iResultRow, 2) = dtDate                    'Date
                            aResults(iResultRow, 3) = aData(iDataRow, 1)        'Area
                            aResults(iResultRow, 4) = aData(iDataRow, 2)        'Reporting Category
                            aResults(iResultRow, 5) = aData(iDataRow, 3)        'Labour Type
                            aResults(iResultRow, 6) = aData(2, iDataCol)        'Name
                            aResults(iResultRow, 7) = aData(1, iDataCol)        'Role
                            aResults(iResultRow, 8) = aData(iDataRow, iDataCol) 'Hours
                            aResults(iResultRow, 9) = aComments(1, iDataCol)    'Comments
                        End If
                    Next iDataCol
                Next iDataRow
                Erase aData
                Erase aComments
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    'Clear previous results and output new results
    If iResultRow > 0 Then
        wsSummary.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
        wsSummary.Range("A2").Resize(iResultRow, UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults
    End If
    
End Sub
```